# How large can a non-standard element of $\omega$ be?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

I realized that the definition of a finite set in ZFC is not the same as a finite set in the intuitive sense. A set is said to be finite if it is equipotent to an integer (i.e. an element of $\omega$). So a non-standard element of $\omega$ is considered finite in ZFC, while they have infinitely many elements (because every natural number is in it). My question is, in the intuitive sense, how large can a non-standard integer be? Can it be uncountable? I don't even know if we are can talk about "cardinality" in the intuitive sense.

Comment: There are no nonstandard elements of $\omega$ “in ZFC”. There are nonstandard *models* of ZFC that have nonstandard elements in *their* natural numbers.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't quite understand the difference. Let's say that in a model of ZFC, the interpretation of $\omega$ has non-standard elements. I am right that all standard integers belongs to such elements?

Comment: It’s not necessarily literally the same sets as the $\omega$ of the metatheory, but there will always be an initial segment that looks like this.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In my textbook, we are always working in a given model of ZFC, and $\omega$ is defined to be the first limit ordinal. I don't know that "$\omega$ of the meta theory" means. Could you explain？

Comment: The metatheory is the background theory you work in to construct the models... generally just the same informal background in which you do any infinitary mathematics. If this is a set theory (as I would typically think of it), we have a "real" $\omega$ that may or may not be the exact same sets as a given model's standard initial segment.

Comment: Whether the "real" $\omega$ is nonstandard or not is one of those unknowable and irrelevant things... the point is we're working in a theory and the things we prove apply equally to all models of that theory. So there's not really a notion of *which* model we're working in.

Comment: (I probably shouldn’t have dismissed it as “irrelevant”... I just meant for most practical purposes.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah I see,  you mean the "real world", not the formal theory or its models.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Frankly I don't know if questions concerning the "real world" should be considered mathematical or philosophical.

Comment: Well, I generally think of "the real world" as being formalized in ZFC or some suitable alternative or extension... or perhaps as some "standard model" thereof. This does get philosophical, but on the practical end it's pretty useful to think about the interaction between the "model you're working in" and the models you construct in it. For example you know that transitive models agree with the metatheory on arithmetical questions since they share the same $V_\omega$, so e.g. any transitive model satisfies Con(ZFC).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't quite understand your last point. I will look at it again once I finish the chapter on ZFC of my textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external size of the natural numbers can be anything. You can see this from a compactness argument. For any infinite cardinality $\kappa,$ add constants $\{c_i:i\in\kappa\}$ to the language, then to ZFC, add the axioms $c_i\ne c_j$ for all $i\ne j,$ and that $c_i$ is a natural number for each $i$. Assuming there is a model of ZFC, then we can use it to satisfy any finite subtheory, and thus the theory has a model, and this model has a set of natural numbers of external size $\kappa.$

And then to address your specific question, since any natural number has all lesser natural numbers as elements, we can find models with natural numbers of any external size.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is just the cardinalities (in the metatheory) of initial segments of the natural numbers in models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, a straightforward compactness argument shows that you can produce a model in which you can embed any linear ordering. Let $(I,<)$ be a linear order and $\mathcal{L}=\{\in,c_i\}_{i\in I}$, where the $c_i$ are new constants; let $\Gamma=\{c_i\in c_j\;|\;i,j\in I\wedge i<j\}\cup \{c_i\in\omega\;|\;i\in I\}$. Clearly $\mathrm{ZFC}\cup\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable (if $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is satisfiable), so $\mathrm{ZFC}\cup\Gamma$ is, too. But a model $M$ of this theory is one in which $(I,<)$ is embedded in what $M$ thinks is $\omega$.

So in such an $M$, an initial segment of $\omega$ can be at least as big as any initial segment of $I$.

(Granted, you don't really need to control things about order types of subsets of $\omega$. It's just fun to do so.)